# "Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:"

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, dns

I have a domain and the email service is being handled by google apps. just recently some of my customers are getting their emails bounced back with the following error stating the message is delayed.

> This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification
>
> THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.
>
> YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.
>
> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>
> christinaseid@chinatownicecreamfactory.com
>
> Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> X-Received: by 10.50.190.199 with SMTP id gs7mr2284940igc.89.1357751042455;
>               Wed, 09 Jan 2013 09:04:02 -0800 (PST)
>   Return-Path: 
>   Received: from mail-ia0-f172.google.com (mail-ia0-f172.google.com [209.85.210.172])
>               by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id py1si4045077igc.32.2013.01.09.09.04.01
>               (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
>               Wed, 09 Jan 2013 09:04:02 -0800 (PST)
>   Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of rosemary.yu@gmail.com designates 209.85.210.172 as permitted sender)
>   client-ip=209.85.210.172;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of rosemary.yu@gmail.com designates 209.85.210.172 as permitted
>   sender) smtp.mail=rosemary.yu@gmail.com; dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com
>   Received: by mail-ia0-f172.google.com with SMTP id u8so1055091iag.3
>               for ; Wed, 09 Jan 2013 09:04:01 -0800 (PST)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>               d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
>               h=mime-version:x-received:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id
>                :subject:from:to:content-type;
>               bh=9DqOa6GJ250rDHuw4CloEtCjzF8XMDn8JFzRVd4muKA=;
>               b=DS3Sx1vK1inuMScD+Rvn15v59PZMSpjIdmgJUFcYvuay0ctyeVv8Z/oSjBbvQCHYvA
>                Y+2u0BYeDKZzz1cL4OPPEze6AwXo3qqLpoHCSuGy7aBQwhBdbfq/+v02OdJ6T5auWjx5
>                GvnuWVAAVUeDsKB8PGgtGZ+G//kSgXWn7J0AoyKOkor19Nz6Az8rWAu/Z07QpglZYrJ7
>                jgRT79qVYKo9Kj13sIzql588yHfo4w0VNl/HbOw1Z+EupfWIdn4v+wIWittiEUaLcwCC
>                ifnq8beSNLm+qtbJqhSOaBBvZvdOVfL0l/r6YCQeT8NGIcQ97Owv9H0tzhFBvknqoHAB
>                PXoQ==
>       MIME-Version: 1.0
>       X-Received: by 10.50.171.103 with SMTP id at7mr2280679igc.21.1357750689214;
>        Wed, 09 Jan 2013 08:58:09 -0800 (PST)
>       Received: by 10.64.81.50 with HTTP; Wed, 9 Jan 2013 08:58:09 -0800 (PST)
>       In-Reply-To: <239C2D3F-5DEB-4449-BEE2-208DC8139AF5@gmail.com>
>       References: 
>               <239C2D3F-5DEB-4449-BEE2-208DC8139AF5@gmail.com>
>       Date: Wed, 9 Jan 2013 11:58:09 -0500
>       Message-ID:

What is the cause of this and anyone fixed this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just an issue with the side of the recipient's. I don't believe that you can do anything on your part except wait. Google automatically resends the mail whenever possible, so your email will end up on your recipient's inbox eventually.

If it is urgent, do use other means to contact the recipient (like using the phone, etc).

Comment: I actually found out the issue. it seems that my domain was hacked and it was sending out spam, 600k emails in fact and most of them were bounce backs which ended up blowing up my entire inbox space. after running out of space, gmail just delays the sending of the emails until its freed up. hope this helps someone.